# radio hardware equipped with device or not android

Tags: android

I want to check Radio hardware equipped with my device or not.

How I get this information?

I use **[Build](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html#getRadioVersion%28%29)** class to get radio information. But got crashed.

```
public final String SUPPORT = "Support";
public final String NOT_SUPPORT = "None";

public String checkRadio() {
    // Radio hardware has or not?

    if (Build.getRadioVersion() != null) {
        return SUPPORT;
    } else {
        return NOT_SUPPORT;
    }
}
```

Error:

```
08-22 15:49:46.662: E/AndroidRuntime(643): java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: android.os.Build.getRadioVersion
08-22 15:49:46.662: E/AndroidRuntime(643):  at com.mobilegenbg.deviceinfo.MainActivity.checkRadio(MainActivity.java:79)
```

**Important**: Build.Radio is deprecated.

any way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is deprecated.

You should consider reading the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Build.html) again, specifically this part:

> This field was deprecated in API level 14. The radio firmware version
>   is frequently not available when this class is initialized, leading to
>   a blank or "unknown" value for this string. Use getRadioVersion()
>   instead.

Also:

`getRadioVersion` is for API 14 and later, it may return null as per this:

> public static String getRadioVersion ()
>
> **Added in API level 14** Returns the version string for the radio
>   firmware. May return null (if, for instance, the radio is not
>   currently on).

Emphasis mine, unless you are running the code on older version of Android?

Or that the device is in Airplane mode or running on emulator?

## Edit

If the `getRadioVersion()` call returns a non-null string, it may be "*unknown*" but did not return a null at least (*Wrap it in a try/catch `NullException` block!*).

That is dependent on the radio firmware and ROM, some may have that specified in the `build.prop`, others may not have it. Which in that case, the absence of it will yield "*unknown*". It is not reliable to use this call regardless as it varies from manufacturer to manufacturer and ROM dependent.

Comment: I am running this with 4.2.2 & after running this in device i got "unknown".

Comment: It may be "unknown" but did not return a `null` at least. That is dependent on the radio firmware and ROM, some may have that specified in the `build.prop`, others may not have it. Which in that case, the absence of it will yield "unknown".

Comment: so,can i guess my device has radio hardware, if it returns unknown? Need a clear information from coding..

Comment: Yes, that is correct. *But* read my edit, it is not reliable, if there was no radio hardware, a `NullPointerException` would be thrown.

Comment: ok..i accept this. if u have better option to check radio hardware presents in device or not kindly inform here. :)